# Unable to access to the inner page of individual recipe derived from json response

Tags: python, python-3.x, web-scraping, python-requests

I'm trying to scrape different recipes from a [webpage](https://www.mealime.com/recipes). What I've written so far can parse all the recipe names from there. However, I can't find any way to access individual recipe link. The following is how each container looks like, in which there is no slug available, so I can't find any clue as to how I can access to the inner page of different recipes:

```
{'id': 748,
 'img': 'https://cdn-uploads.mealime.com/uploads/recipe/thumbnail/41/thumbnail_708f7645-6cb4-4089-8e18-95f5b97cbbcf.jpg',
 'name': 'Apple Quinoa Salad with Celery, Almonds & Dried Cranberries',
 'recipeId': 41,
 'restrictions': [6],
 'types': [1, 3, 2, 4]}
```

If I'm not wrong, this is `https://www.mealime.com/_next/data/kSmAjTn7MJl4zVPNE6MeR/recipes/greek-turkey-meatball-pita-wraps-veggies-olives-feta-sauce/14887.json` what an individual recipe link should look like which leads to the inner page.

I've tried with:

```
import requests
from pprint import pprint

link = 'https://www.mealime.com/_next/data/kSmAjTn7MJl4zVPNE6MeR/recipes.json'

with requests.Session() as s:
    s.headers['User-Agent'] = 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/88.0.4324.150 Safari/537.36'
    res = s.get(link)
    for item in res.json()['pageProps']['reducedVariants']:
        pprint(item)
```

> How can I access to the inner page of individual recipe derived from json response?

Comment: So you want link of every receipe from that URL?

Comment: Yeah but not using this `https://www.mealime.com/recipes`. I would like to parse individual recipe which are supposed to be like [this](https://www.mealime.com/_next/data/kSmAjTn7MJl4zVPNE6MeR/recipes/greek-turkey-meatball-pita-wraps-veggies-olives-feta-sauce/14887.json) @Bhavya Parikh.

Comment: you need only names ? or !!!

Comment: I need name and ingredients. However, I can grab them all using this link `https://www.mealime.com/recipes`. But, my question is different. I would to parse the two fields using the json response. Data in there is useless to me. All I wanna know is the logic by which I can achieve what I've asked in my question. Thanks.

Comment: Why didn't you extract from the script tag?

Answer (score 1):

Here I have done for one you can use for all but `name` can contain unnecssary words which has to remove and then we can make request agian and you can get desired output:

```
import requests
from pprint import pprint
import re

main_url="https://www.mealime.com/_next/data/kSmAjTn7MJl4zVPNE6MeR/recipes"
json=".json"

with requests.Session() as s:
    s.headers['User-Agent'] = 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/88.0.4324.150 Safari/537.36'

    res = s.get(main_url+json)      
    main_data=res.json()

    for i in range(len(main_data['pageProps']['reducedVariants'])):
        if main_data['pageProps']['reducedVariants'][i]['id']==14887:
            name=main_data['pageProps']['reducedVariants'][i]['name'].replace("with","")
            id_=main_data['pageProps']['reducedVariants'][i]['id']
            name="-".join(re.findall("[a-zA-Z]+", name.lower()))
            detail_res=requests.get(main_url+"/"+name+"/"+str(id_)+json)
            print(detail_res.json()['pageProps']['publishedRecipe']['line_items'])
```

Output:

```
[{'id': 258630, 'quantity': '1 (4 oz) pkg', 'ingredient_name': 'crumbled feta cheese'}, {'id': 258637, 'quantity': '2', 'ingredient_name': 'eggs'}, {'id': 258641, 'quantity': '1', 'ingredient_name': 'English cucumber'}, {'id': 258647, 'quantity': '1 small bunch', 'ingredient_name': 'fresh dill'}, {'id': 258629, 'quantity': '4 cloves', 'ingredient_name': 'garlic'},....
```

Comment: What does `main_url` contain in your script?

Comment: So, you had to manipulate string to create slugs like `greek-turkey-meatball-pita-wraps-veggies-olives-feta-sauce`. Usually they are available in json response. However, it seems to be missing here.

Comment: oh sorry i havent mention that i will update it  yes you need to manipulate name. yes it is missing so you have to call another url

Comment: Okay, you solution works until it encounter names like `Balsamic Chicken Drumsticks  Garlic & Parsley Sautéed Carrots` in which ***é*** causes trouble and as a result leads to value error.